Third-Party scripts and iframes not Loading on Page Navigation with Sitecore JSS Link in Next.js
I'm using Next.js with Sitecore JSS in a headless project, and I have a problem with loading third-party scripts and iframes when navigating between pages.
What’s happening:

If I use Sitecore's <Link> component to move between pages (for
single-page app behavior), the third-party scripts and iframes don’t
load on the new page.
If I use a regular <a> tag instead, everything works fine, but I lose the single-page app feature.
If I refresh the page manually, both scripts and iframes load correctly.
I also tried using Next.js' <Link> with prefetch={false}, which fixes the script
issue, but the iframe still won’t load.

I want to keep the single-page app experience but also make sure the third-party scripts and iframes load correctly when I navigate between pages.
Script example, which is now working with next <Link> with prefetch={false} I have added like this, as it is render script based on div id and data-bv-product-id
<div
 data-bv-show="rating_summary"
 data-bv-product-id={bvProductId}
 id="ratingSummary"
 className="ratingSummary"
 />

iframe example: this will render iframe based on data-widget-id and data-src
<div
 className="ct-widget"
 data-widget-id={item.fields.widgetId?.value}
 data-src= {item.fields.widgetUrl?.url}
 />


Can you give examples of how you are adding scripts and iframes?

Have you tried adding scripts to Scripts.tsx which gets loaded on Layout.tsx?

And @AkashSavalagi in my case, i don't need script and iframe on every page it is component specific and i need to pass div with proper attributes and it will works

Added example @RichardSeal

I faced the same issue with Next.js where third party scripts and iframes didn't load correctly when using the <Link> component. I have listed some approaches you can try to resolve it:

Dynamic Script loading
considering using useEffect hook to dynamically load script when the component mounts. This ensures that scripts are available for the current page context.

Custom Hook for Script Management
You can create a custom hook to manage the loading and unloading of scripts. This will help to keep your code organized and allow for easy reuse across different components.

Event Listener for Route Changes
Try to leveraging Next.js's Scripts and iframes whenever users navigate between pages, ensuring they work correctly.

Context API for Global Management
You might want to use the Context API to manage the loading state of scripts globally. This can reduce redundancy and make easier to maintain your script logic in one place.

Server-Side Loading Considerations
Consider whether any of your scripts can be loaded server-side to improve performance and ensure that critical data is available right away.


your scenario might be different, but these approaches could help you to manage third-party scripts and iframes more effectively.
hope this can help !

Yes, It is working with dynamic script loading using useEffect
